# How to make the binomial symbol look better?

Tags: fonts, amsmath

I am using `\binom{\mathcal{L}}{k}` with the following font (see code sample below), and I'd like the parenthesis to completely "capture" `\mathcal{L}` and `k` as they do if I use the default font. (If you comment out the last three commands before `\begin{document}`, so that default fonts are used, the thing looks nice.)

Here's how it looks like in PDF (compiled with `pdflatex`):

[image]

How can I deal with this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{courier}
\linespread{1.05} % Palatino looks better with this

\begin{document}
    The following binomial is ugly: $\binom{n}{k}$.

    The problem is even more pronounced here: $\binom{\mathcal{L}}{k}$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `\binom` *is* defined in terms of `\genfrac`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `\genfrac` is defined in terms of the primitive `\abovewithdelims`, which obeys slightly different rules from `\left` and `\right` when it comes to deciding the size of the delimiters.

Comment: @egreg: I leave it to you -- you answered already. I am deleting my foolish comment

Comment: @egreg: Well, I’d say that `\abovewithdelims` follows *quite* different rules from `\left` and `\right`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find neither so ugly as you say. You could use `\left` and `\right`, but in the comparison the standard `\binom` wins, in my opinion.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.05} % Palatino looks better with this

\newcommand\test[2]{\mleft(\knds\genfrac..{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}\knds\mright)}
\newcommand{\knds}{\kern-\nulldelimiterspace}

\begin{document}

The following binomial is ugly: $\binom{n}{k}=\test{n}{k}$.

The problem is even more pronounced here:
$\binom{\mathcal{L}}{k}=\test{\mathcal{L}}{k}$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using `\left` and `\right` screws up vertical spacing in the text. (I'm using the `\binom` command inline in text.)

Comment: The first case is actually nicely handled with your solution; thanks! I'll try to find a workaround for the second case.